# gerunds: difference between "on doing", "by doing", and "in doing"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, gerunds

What is the difference between "on doing", "by doing", and "in doing"?

A difficult point to French learners of English as in all three cases, you would say "en faisant".

Example sentences, taken from the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*:

*What was your reaction on seeing him?*

*Howard had put his own life in danger in trying to protect the Queen.*

*She earns her living by selling insurance.*

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: Prepositions are typically weak meaning words, in the sense that some can be interchanged with little loss in meaning.

Comment: And also correspondences between the usages of French say and English prepositions are not one-to-one but _often_ fairly unpredictable.

Comment: Ok, got it, Kris. So, I will save my trickiest questions  – where even native speakers of English might be at a loss – for this website and ask the others on the website you redirected me to! Provided I can work out such questions…

Comment: Of course, Edwin. Would not life be dull if languages allowed for (?) literal translations… !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between "on leaving" on the one hand and "by selling" and "in trying" on the other hand is easy: "on leaving" is to do with time and means "when you saw him", whereas "by selling" and "in trying" are to do with the cause and effect relationship.
But there is a difference: **by** = she sells insurance **in order to** earn a living, it is her aim, it is a means to an end; **in** = Howard does **not** try to protect the Queen **in order to** put his own life in danger, it is just an occupational hazard for bodyguards, a side effect.